Ubuntu freezes a few seconds after power cable is disconnected from laptop (or when started on battery)
My laptop is using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Windows/Ubuntu dual boot, with Ubuntu on an external SSD), with an AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX (with Radeon Graphics) and NVIDIA RTX3060.
The system works fine as long as I have the laptop connected to the AC Power adapter. However, when the power adapter is disconnected, my system will immediately freeze (or freeze after a few seconds). If the laptop is started without the adapter, similar behaviors occur (freezing after a few seconds). What steps can I take to diagnose this?
